# Django 2.0 - Annotate Conditional Max() field

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have `Employee` model and `Invitation` model. Every `Employee` has an `one-to-many` relation with `Invitation`. `Invitation` has a `send_date` and `active` column.

**What I want:**

I want to get `Employee QuerySet` with annotated highest `send_date` of related **active only** `Invitations`.

**My Models:**

```
# App is named events

class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default="")

class Invitation(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey('events.Employee', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='invitations')
    send_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

**What I Tried:**

```
query = Employee.objects.annotate(
    invitation_max_send_date=Max(
        Case(
            When(
                invitations__active=True,
                then=F('invitations__send_date')
            ),
            When(
                invitations__active=False,
                then=None
            ),
            output_field=models.DateField()
        )
    ),
)
```

**Result:** 
`invitation_max_send_date` of each `Employee` contains the highest `send_date` of related invitations, regardless if are `active` or not.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the code of your models?

Comment: I added those as you requested.

Comment: Your query is working fine for me, I get the latest `send_date` of active invitations.

Comment: @Fusion what db engine do you use? I am asking cause for instance with sqlite I am getting invitation_max_send_date as `None` for any situation with this output_field (your model field is DateTimeField and you output it as DateField). The actual data would be useful too.